# css last-child matches all children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to use create a separator between my links by creating a border on the right side of each of them.  Then on the last one, remove it.  I have the following html and css but what I'm finding is that each "a" tag matches the last-child selector.  I'm not clear why and what the proper way would be to do this.

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
</ul>


.nav a { border-right:solid 1px #000;}
.nav a:last-child { border-right-width:0px;}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's because each `a` is the last-child of its parent `li`. You'd want something like `.nav li:last-child a` instead.

Answer (score 1):

All your `<a>` tags are last children of their parent `<li>`